# How to calculate GRID_UNIT_PX

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want calculate a GRID_UNIT_PX for the 1280*720 5" 295 PPI display.
What the math formula do I use?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting#Screen_Pixel_Ratio
There is no a particular formula, and varies between phone/tablet

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. While this link might provide a suitable answer to this question, link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Consider [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/506663/edit) your answer to provide a small explanation of what the link contains, so that it is persistent in case the link disapear